# Xamarin, translating Java to C#: Bundle does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to convert a small self-made app from Java code to C#.

Now I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting `The name 'savedInstanceState' does not exist in the current context`.
You'll find `savedInstanceState` in the first method:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Java.Util;
using Android.OS;
using System.Linq;
using AkvaC;

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Util;
using Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.App;
using Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views;
using IMenu = Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.IMenu;
using IMenuItem = Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.IMenuItem;
using MenuItem = Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.MenuItem;
using ISubMenu = Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.ISubMenu;

namespace AkvaC
{
    public class Support13Demos : ListActivity {

        Bundle savedInstanceState;

        public override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = Intent();
            String path = intent.GetStringExtra("com.Pynting.Akvaapp.Apis.Path");

            if (path == null) {
                path = "";
            }

            ListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (this, GetData (path),
                Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, new String[] { "title" },
                new int[] { Android.Resource.Id.Text1 });
            ListView.TextFilterEnabled = true;
        }

        protected IList<IDictionary<string,object>> GetData (string prefix)
        {
            List<IDictionary<string, Object>> myData = new List<IDictionary<string, Object>>();

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain, null);
            mainIntent.AddCategory("com.Pynting.Akvaapp.SUPPORT13_SAMPLE_CODE");

            PackageManager pm = PackageManager();

            var list = pm.QueryIntentActivities (mainIntent, 0);

            if (null == list)
                return myData;

            String[] prefixPath;
            String prefixWithSlash = prefix;

            if (prefix == "") {
                prefixPath = null;
            } else {
                prefixPath = prefix.Split ('/');
                prefixWithSlash = prefix + "/";
            }

            int len = list.Count();

            Dictionary<String, Boolean> entries = new Dictionary<String, Boolean>();

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                ResolveInfo info = list [i];
                var labelSeq = info.LoadLabel (pm);
                String label = labelSeq != null
                    ? labelSeq.ToString ()
                    : info.ActivityInfo.Name;
                if (prefixWithSlash.Length == 0 || label.StartsWith (prefixWithSlash)) {
                    String[] labelPath = label.Split ('/');
                    String nextLabel = prefixPath == null ? labelPath [0] : labelPath [prefixPath.Length];
                    if ((prefixPath != null ? prefixPath.Length : 0) == labelPath.Length - 1) {
                        AddItem (myData, nextLabel, ActivityIntent (
                            info.ActivityInfo.ApplicationInfo.PackageName,
                            info.ActivityInfo.Name));
                    } else {
                        if (entries.ContainsKey (nextLabel)) {
                            AddItem (myData, nextLabel, BrowseIntent (prefix == "" ? nextLabel : prefix + "/" + nextLabel));
                            entries [nextLabel] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            myData.Sort (sDisplayNameComparator);

            return myData;
        }

        private readonly static Comparison<IDictionary<string, object>> sDisplayNameComparator = (map1, map2) => {
            return string.Compare (ToString (map1 ["title"]), ToString (map2 ["title"]));
        };

        static string ToString (Object obj)
        {
            return obj != null ? obj.ToString () : null;
        }

        protected Intent ActivityIntent (string pkg, string componentName)
        {
            Intent result = new Intent ();
            result.SetClassName (pkg, componentName);
            return result;
        }
        protected Intent BrowseIntent (string path)
        {
            Intent result = new Intent ();
            result.SetClass (this, typeof(SampleList));
            result.PutExtra ("com.example.android.apis.Path", path);
            return result;
        }
        protected void AddItem (IList<IDictionary<String, Object>> data, string name, Intent intent)
        {
            var temp = new JavaDictionary<string, Object> ();
            temp ["title"] = name;
            temp ["intent"] = intent;
            data.Add (temp);
        }
        // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected override void OnListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            var map = (IDictionary<String, Object>)l.GetItemAtPosition (position);
            Intent intent = (Intent)map ["intent"];
            StartActivity (intent);
        }
}
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I copied this code into Xamarin Studio and there were a few bits of syntax errors that I ran into.

Your missing a closing bracket at the end of the file (I'm assuming it was just forgotten when copy/pasting)

```
public override void onCreate
```

Should be

```
protected override void OnCreate
```

You're missing a "new" keyword when creating the intent inside the OnCreate method.

PackageManager is a property not a method so you can remove the parenthesis.

I'm assuming these syntax errors were indirectly causing the error you stated. After those items I was able to build without error. Hope this helps